# Принцип работы ссылки на Cursor

Tags: android, cursor

Понимаю, что тема с `Cursor`'ами "избитая", но все же спрошу. Вот классический запрос в БД.

```
    DatabaseHelper sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " +
                    DatabaseHelper.TABLE_MAIN + " where " +
                    DatabaseHelper.MAIN_MAX + " = " + max,
            null);
```

`Cursor` это `Interface`, в нем нет реализации непосредственно в методах, её (реализацию) нужно реализовать имплементируя интерфейс в некотором `Классе`. Сам `Cursor` -  `extends Closeable`, а `SQLiteDatabase` - `extends SQLiteClosable`, который в свою очередь `implements Closeable`. В `Closeable` только метод `close`.

В примере мы присваиваем результат запроса `db.rawQuery(...)` ссылке `Cursor`.

Интересует следующее. 
Что за `Класс` "кроется" за ссылкой `cursor`, что реализует непосредственно методы `cursor.moveToFirst()`, `cursor.moveToLast()` и т.д.? Как может ссылка `Interface`'а манипулировать данными?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cursor` это интерфейс, то есть набор абстрактных методов, которые должны имплементироваться конкретным классом.

В вашем случае, это класс `SQLiteCursor`, который `extends AbstractWindowedCursor`, который `extends AbstractCursor`, который `implements CrossProcessCursor`, который `implements Cursor`.

Если хотите порыться в кишках как это реализовано - [посмотрите сюда](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java#SQLiteCursor) - это исходники `SQLiteCursor`

Comment: Значит компилятор пробегает по реализовавшим/затронутым `Cursor`/ом классам, в данном случае в обратном порядке в вами указанной цепочке и вызывает то, что нужно. Пример того, как "хвост (интерфейс) веляет собакой (имплементировавшим его классом)" если можно так выразиться?

Comment: Не советую пытаться вникнуть в методы работы компилятора - окончательно вынесете себе мозг. Там существуют разные способы интерфейсов/классов